# What NOT to hard-code in an Android Application

Tags: java, android, api, security, connection-string

I understand that putting DB connection strings with the credentials in, API-Key's etc is really bad as you can de-compile it to see the values...

So doe's everything need to be behind an API?

For example what actually does need to be put behind a web service:

Does an SQL query need to be put behind a web-service or can we do parameterized query's to stored procedures and that would be okay? I'm assuming this also needs to be behind a web service and just return something like a JSON array etc.

I've not really seen any sort of checklist of what not to put behind a web service for a mobile app.

I'm coming from the position of web development so this hasn't really been an issue until now.

Do we basically need to run our apps through a web-service and if so how do we go about then incorporating the web service with the app since we can't hard-code a key for the web-service in the first place?

Summary:

Do we need to create an all-encompasing web-service for the purpose of exchanging between the database and the android app client, the same for any 3rd party API?

Also, how do we authorize an android app to interact with our web-service since the purpose of this web service was to prevent hard-coding keys in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand that putting DB connection strings with the credentials in, API-Key's etc is really bad as you can de-compile it to see the values...

YES, this is extremely bad in any kind of app, not matter if mobile, web or IOT app.

> So doe's everything need to be behind an API?

YES, your app needs to be as dumb as possible. By other words the code in your app should be only concerned as much as possible with presentation, any business logic should be delegated to the API server. This approach have the tremendous advantage that anytime you have a bug, you only need to update the API server, not the app itself, and wait for all clients to update them in their mobile devices. In case of web apps you don't want to reveal your business logic to anyone that hits F12 in the browser, and starts debugging your code in the developer tools panel.

> Does an SQL query need to be put behind a web-service or can we do parameterized query's to stored procedures and that would be okay?

As I said previous the APP must be as dumb as possible and NEVER do SQL queries from a client to any type of backend, otherwise you are opening a huge security hole in your service.

Anything that comes from the client side to your a backend must be considered as potentially malicious, because even when you think you know the **WHO** is making the request, you may not know **WHAT** is making it. For a better understanding of the difference between **WHO** and **WHAT** is accessing your server, please read [this article](https://blog.approov.io/why-does-your-mobile-app-need-an-api-key) in the section where you this picture:

[image: Man in the Middle Attack]

So in short the **WHO** means the user and the **WHAT** means the application/device doing the request, and as the image suggests it can be be tampered by an attacker with a Man in the Middle attack.

> I'm assuming this also needs to be behind a web service and just return something like a JSON array etc.

Json is the most used format to return responses from an API, because is easy to read by humans and machines, but other formats exist.

> I've not really seen any sort of checklist of what not to put behind a web service for a mobile app.

While the list you are asking for may not exist, because is to broad, you can start by avoiding the [OWASP Mobile Security Project - Top 10 risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#Top_Ten_Mobile_Risks) in your mobile app.

> I'm coming from the position of web development so this hasn't really been an issue until now.

While you may not be using API keys in your web app, if you are doing SQL queries from them, then you are at risk of SQL injection, the most common risk present in any application that is exposed to the internet, that continues to be in the first position at the [OWASP Top 10 - 2017](https://www.owasp.org/images/7/72/OWASP_Top_10-2017_%28en%29.pdf.pdf)(pdf).

> Do we basically need to run our apps through a web-service

YES, you need to run your mobile apps though an API server.

> and if so how do we go about then incorporating the web service with the app since we can't hard-code a key for the web-service in the first place?

As I demonstrate in the article [How to Extract an API Key from a Mobile App by Static binary analysis](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-extract-an-api-key-from-a-mobile-app-with-static-binary-analysis) it can be extracted with the help of several open source tools, like by using the [Mobile Security Framework](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF), but you can also grab the API key with a MitM attack, as I show in the article [Steal that API Key with a Man in the Middle Attack](https://blog.approov.io/steal-that-api-key-with-a-man-in-the-middle-attack), that uses the open source tool [MiTM Proxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/).

So now what... If I use an API key it can be extracted, but if I don't use one I cannot identify **WHAT** is making the request.

You can resort now to employ several layers of defense, starting with [reCaptcha V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html), followed by [Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall)(WAF) and finally if you can afford it a [User Behavior Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_behavior_analytics)(UBA) solution.

Google [reCAPTCHA V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html):

> reCAPTCHA is a free service that protects your website from spam and abuse. reCAPTCHA uses an advanced risk analysis engine and adaptive challenges to keep automated software from engaging in abusive activities on your site. It does this while letting your valid users pass through with ease.
>
> ...helps you detect abusive traffic on your website without any user friction. It returns a score based on the interactions with your website and provides you more flexibility to take appropriate actions.

[WAF - Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall):

> A web application firewall (or WAF) filters, monitors, and blocks HTTP traffic to and from a web application. A WAF is differentiated from a regular firewall in that a WAF is able to filter the content of specific web applications while regular firewalls serve as a safety gate between servers. By inspecting HTTP traffic, it can prevent attacks stemming from web application security flaws, such as SQL injection, cross-site scripting (XSS), file inclusion, and security misconfigurations.

[UBA - User Behavior Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_behavior_analytics):

> User behavior analytics (UBA) as defined by Gartner is a cybersecurity process about detection of insider threats, targeted attacks, and financial fraud. UBA solutions look at patterns of human behavior, and then apply algorithms and statistical analysis to detect meaningful anomalies from those patterns—anomalies that indicate potential threats. Instead of tracking devices or security events, UBA tracks a system's users. Big data platforms like Apache Hadoop are increasing UBA functionality by allowing them to analyze petabytes worth of data to detect insider threats and advanced persistent threats.

All this solutions work based on a negative identification model, by other words they try their best to differentiate the bad from the good by identifying what is bad, not what is good, thus they are prone to false positives, despite of the advanced technology used by some of them, like machine learning and artificial intelligence.

So you may find yourself more often than not in having to relax how you block the access to the API server in order to not affect the good users. This also means that this solutions require constant monitoring to validate that the false positives are not blocking your legit users and that at same time they are properly keeping at bay the unauthorized ones.

Regarding APIs serving mobile apps a positive identification model can be used by using a Mobile App Attestation solution that guarantees to the API server that the requests can be trusted without the possibility of false positives.

## Mobile App Attestation

Use a Mobile App Attestation solution to enable the API server to know is receiving only requests from a genuine mobile app.

The role of a Mobile App Attestation service is to guarantee at run-time that your mobile app was not tampered or is not running in a rooted device by running a SDK in the background that will communicate with a service running in the cloud to attest the integrity of the mobile app and device is running on.

On successful attestation of the mobile app integrity a short time lived JWT token is issued and signed with a secret that only the API server and the Mobile App Attestation service in the cloud are aware. In the case of failure on the mobile app attestation the JWT token is signed with a secret that the API server does not know.

Now the App must sent with every API call the JWT token in the headers of the request. This will allow the API server to only serve requests when it can verify the signature and expiration time in the JWT token and refuse them when it fails the verification.

Once the secret used by the Mobile App Attestation service is not known by the mobile app, is not possible to reverse engineer it at run-time even when the App is tampered, running in a rooted device or communicating over a connection that is being the target of a Man in the Middle Attack.

The Mobile App Attestation service already exists as a SAAS solution at Approov(I work here) that provides SDKs for several platforms, including iOS, Android, React Native and others. The integration will also need a small check in the API server code to verify the JWT token issued by the cloud service. This check is necessary for the API server to be able to decide what requests to serve and what ones to deny.

## Replying to Your Summary

> Do we need to create an all-encompasing web-service for the purpose of exchanging between the database and the android app client, the same for any 3rd party API?

YES, and the you should always delegate access to third party services in any kind of app, mobile, web or IOT app, otherwise you will get in trouble when an attacker grabs the credentials to access them and starts using them on your behalf, while you will be the one paying the bill.

> Also, how do we authorize an android app to interact with our web-service since the purpose of this web service was to prevent hard-coding keys in the first place?

A Mobile App Attestation solution looks the best fit here.

## In Conclusion

Anything that runs on the client side and needs some secret to access an API can be abused in different ways and you must delegate the access to all third part APIs to a backend under your control, so that you reduce the attack surface, and at the same time protect their secrets from public pry eyes.

In the end, the solution to use in order to protect your API server must be chosen in accordance with the value of what you are trying to protect and the legal requirements for that type of data, like the GDPR regulations in Europe.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you will make a backend service which will expose some APIs for your app to use

EG you could have an API at myserver.com/something this will be a PHP script or some other server side language. This will return the data the app needs to display. You encode the data using something like JSON and the app can read this using a suitable library.

Sending data works similarly, make an API which can accept POST requests over HTTP and store the data back in to the database. The login and the SQL should all be on the server side.

Eg app sends request to server.com/storeInformation with parameters someInfo="hello world"

The server side (eg php) then does the query INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (...whatever..)

The point is the client side app never needs to send SQL directly (as this cannot be trusted) instead it should send what it wants to be done and the server decides how it is done.

As a rule, remember that the client can NEVER be trusted. Anyone can call your server APIs with any parameters.

Comment: But how do I make sure only my app can use my web service?

Comment: @Sanguine you cannot. You need to build everything with that in mind. This is why you cannot let the front end app send SQL commands because you cannot know that only your app is sending them. Please tell us what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Imagine logging in with a user account. I only want certain users to be able to access certain bits of data from the DB. Would I then have to send up their login details to authenticate every time they want to retrieve something?

Comment: @Sanguine yes exactly. For starters you could do that, remember the password and username on the app side and then send these again with every request (in future you should look at better techniques than storing the password). Remember: every request on your server must be treated as if it might be from a malicious person